# Echarts legend with custom style

Tags: javascript, charts, echarts

I have this chart with legends labels and values added after.
I want to achieve something like:
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrruB.png)

Always have a space between the label and its value (something like flex: justify-between).
Tried `align` as described in the Echarts doc but seems it does not help in this case.

```js
var dom = document.getElementById('chart-container');
var myChart = echarts.init(dom, 'dark', {
  renderer: 'canvas',
  useDirtyRect: false
});
var app = {};

var option;

const dataList = [
  { value: 1048, name: 'Search Engine', count: 245 },
  { value: 735, name: 'Direct', count: 56 },
  { value: 580, name: 'Email', count: 45 },
  { value: 484, name: 'Union Ads', count: 21 },
  { value: 300, name: 'Video Ads', count: 54 }
];

option = {
  title: {
    text: 'Referer of a Website',
    subtext: 'Fake Data',
    left: 'center'
  },
  tooltip: {
    trigger: 'item'
  },
  legend: {
    orient: 'vertical',
    left: 'left',
    formatter: function (name) {
      return `${name} {count|${dataList
        .filter((a) => a.name === name)
        .map((a) => a.count)}}`;
    },
    textStyle: {
      rich: {
        'count': {
          align: 'right',
          color: 'red'
        }
      }
    }
  },
  series: [
    {
      name: 'Access From',
      type: 'pie',
      radius: '50%',
      data: dataList,
      emphasis: {
        itemStyle: {
          shadowBlur: 10,
          shadowOffsetX: 0,
          shadowColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)'
        }
      }
    }
  ]
};


if (option && typeof option === 'object') {
  myChart.setOption(option);
}

window.addEventListener('resize', myChart.resize);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#chart-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Referer of a Website - Apache ECharts Demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart-container"></div>
    <script src="https://fastly.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts@5.4.0/dist/echarts.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: found the solution in case somebody will need it:
Simply add and empty element withing the formatter between name and value:
`{name|${name}} {divider|} {count|${options}}`
` rich: {
        name: {
          width: 0
        },
        divider: {
          width: "100%"
        },
        count: {
          width: 70,
          align: "center"
        }
      }
`

Answer (score 0):

Already answered by the Author, still it was little hard for me to understand the comment. I thought I will add the code with better format and  link to [documentation](https://echarts.apache.org/en/tutorial.html#Rich%20Text)

The working code would look like

```
legend: {
    orient: 'vertical',
    left: 'left',
    formatter: function (name) {
      return `${name} {count|${dataList
        .filter((a) => a.name === name)
        .map((a) => a.count)}}`;
    },
    textStyle: {
      rich: {
        'count': {
          align: 'right',
          color: 'red'
        }
      }
    }
  }
```